# magento meta description not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, meta

I'm hoping someone out there can help me :)

I'm running Magento 1.9 - everything seems to be working pretty much out of the box, but I am having issues with the Meta Descrioptions not appearing correctly in Google results.

If I view the homepage source it has this:

```
<meta name="description" content="Up to date ladies fashion at affordable prices. " />
```

However the Google results look like:

```
Sitti Boutique
www.sittiboutique.co.uk/
Sitti Boutique. Sitti Boutique. Menu Search Account. Cart 0. Recently added item(s) ×. You have no items in your shopping cart. Dresses · Tops · Shorts ...
```

It is doing this to the homepage, category pages, and product pages.

Can anyone suggest anything please.  I've had a look on the web, but can't seem to find anyone else thats had this issue.

I haven't changed the description for over a month, so Google should have picked this up.

If anyone has any thoughts, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: How you are getting the google result ??

Comment: Simply by typing in "Sitti Boutique" into Google

Answer (score 3):

What i understood that Google database still not updated.

You can do following

1)Generate sitemap.xml and place in your site root.

2)Put robot.txt in your site root.

3)Make your keyword formatted. Now there are many empty spaces before after.

It should be like follwing

```
<meta name="description" content="Up to date ladies fashion at affordable prices." />
<meta name="keywords" content="Fashion,boutique,ladies,dress,shirt,necklace" />
```

Comment: Thank you Suman, I have already generated the sitemap.xml, and the robots.txt.  I will format the description, but would be surprised if the space at the end would make much of a difference.